# Como configurar VPS Ubuntu 14.04.4 para app en NodeJS?

Tags: javascript, nodejs

Mi consulta es la siguiente:

Tengo una app hecha en nodeJS y Express, usa SocketIO para extraer datos en tiempo real de Twitter.

¿Cuál es el procedimiento para pasar mi app a un VPS de tal modo que al hacer 
`sudo reboot` se ejecute mi app en el puerto especifico ( dado por el `server.listen()` ) en Nodejs ?

¿Algun link a aportar?

Y si tengo dos o mas app en distintos puertos, ¿cómo configuro todo esto?

Gracias por las futuras respuestas !!

> VPS con Ubuntu 14.04.4

Comment: Hay muchas respuestas posibles a esta pregunta y la mayoría son muy amplias. Si te interesa usar un container como Docker para distribuir la aplicación, aquí tienes algo de información oficial, lamentablemente en inglés, https://nodejs.org/en/docs/guides/nodejs-docker-webapp/

Comment: O esta otra, no oficial, pero no es exactamente tu caso pues el VPS ya estaría virtualizado. https://seanmcgary.com/posts/deploying-a-nodejs-application-using-docker

Comment: También tienes otras herramientas como `pm2`, http://pm2.keymetrics.io/, la cual estoy usando desde hace unos 2 años en un VPS con 256Mb de ram y funciona muy bien.

Comment: Gracias a todos, Docker no me convence ya que seria VPS + Docker (capa sobre capa ) , pm2 es NodeJS, o sea ejecutar algo de NodeJS para que me ejecute NodeJS. Pero nada si esto es lo que hay, tratare de investigar en estos links que ustedes me dieron, gracias nuevamente !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pues hay varias opciones , podrias hacer uso de PM2 `npm install pm2 -g` -> `pm2 start app.js`, te dara como un pequeño dashboard en la consola donde puedes ver si esta habilitada tu aplicacion, el pid, status, etc. 
La otra es usar forever o supervisor, aunque este ultimo no lo he usado, con forever técnicamente tu aplicación estara ejecutándose continuamente.

Comment: Gracias tomare en cuenta tus comendaciones

Answer (score 2):

A mí me ha servido mucho utilizar esta guía: https://www.exratione.com/2013/02/nodejs-and-forever-as-a-service-simple-upstart-and-init-scripts-for-ubuntu/

Y me gusta porque podes fácilmente levantar, bajar o reiniciar el servicio desde la línea de comandos (si es un ambiente en producción que no tenga interfaz gráfica) y cada app la manejas por separado.

```
start my-application
status my-application
restart my-application
stop my-application
```

Comment: Voy a leer la guia a ver que tal me va.. ! Gracias Wanderson !

Answer (score 0):

si estas en produccion todavia, desde la carpeta ejecuta "node nodescript.js" y eso hara que se ejecute el script.Para distribuición usa "forever" que deja en segundo plano ejecutandose el script siempre en el servidor.